# Spring Batch Async Processor - AsyncItemProcessor does not take effect ,getting Job status COMPLETED on start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to implement a simple spring batch job

The goal is  perform a select query on  DB using JpaItemReader and process All itens in a Async way

I following this example -> https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/blob/master/single-jvm-demos/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/scalingdemos/asyncprocessor/AsyncProcessorJobApplication.java

If I run this code in a single thread and it works fine

But when I add Async process, looks like the job
change the state to COMPLETED without wait for execution of Process()

May I possible miss something in this script?

Here is the Result of Console:

```
2019-11-07 10:15:10.672 [main] T: INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=92, version=21, name=step1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=1872, filterCount=0, writeCount=1872 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=19, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription= 
2019-11-07 10:15:10.693 [main] T: INFO  c.s.g.G.JobCompletionNotificationListener - !!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results 
2019-11-07 10:15:10.702 [main] T: INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=reCalculate]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 74ms 
201


>** Here is my Class**


import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.batch.poc.common.Position;



@Component
public class PositionRecalculationBatchExecutorAsync {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PositionRecalculationBatchExecutorAsync.class);

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 450;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired public EntityManagerFactory emf;


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public   JpaPagingItemReader<Position> read( ) throws Exception{
        JpaPagingItemReader<Position> positionBatchReader = new  JpaPagingItemReader<>();

        positionBatchReader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT ")
                .append(" pos ")
                .append(" FROM ")
                .append(" Position pos");


        positionBatchReader.setQueryString( query.toString() );
        positionBatchReader.setPageSize(400);
        positionBatchReader.setSaveState(false);
        positionBatchReader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return positionBatchReader;

    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public  JpaItemWriter<Position> update() {
        //Not in Use
        JpaItemWriter<Position>  positionBatchWriter = new JpaItemWriter<> ();
        return positionBatchWriter;
    }

    @Bean public Job reCalculate(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws Exception { 
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("reCalculate") 
                .start(step1() )
                .listener(listener)
                .build(); 
    }

    @Bean public PositionItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PositionItemProcessor(); 
    }



    @Bean 
    public AsyncItemProcessor<Position, Position>  asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception {
        AsyncItemProcessor<Position, Position> p =  new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        p.setDelegate(processor());
        p.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        p.afterPropertiesSet();
        return p;

    }

    @Bean 
    @StepScope
    public AsyncItemWriter<Position> asyncItemWriter(){
        log.info("!!! JOB asyncItemWriter!!");
        AsyncItemWriter<Position> writer = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDelegate(this.update());
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        log.info("!!!  step1 !!");

        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Position, Position> chunk(100)
                .reader(read())
                .processor(  (ItemProcessor) asyncItemProcessor() )
                .writer( asyncItemWriter() )
                .build();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I add Async process, looks like the job change the state to COMPLETED

It looks like you have executed the job the first time with a regular processor (here the step was executed and completed) and then run the same job after adding the async processor (here it sees the step as completed hence the message `Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute`).

You can set the `allowStartIfComplete` flag on the step definition if you want to re-run it even if it's complete:

```
@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    log.info("!!!  step1 !!");

    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Position, Position> chunk(100)
            .reader(read())
            .processor(  (ItemProcessor) asyncItemProcessor() )
            .writer( asyncItemWriter() )
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Hey Mahmoud, thanks a lot for the tip!   You are right, I looked at the Job execution table, and it was marked as COMPLETED, I really appreciate your help.